# Necesito ayuda con el siguiente trabajo de varias preguntas

Tags: python

pregunta 1:
:Escriba una función que reciba un string consistente de unos y ceros y retorne la cantidad de ocurrencias de unos menos la cantidad de ocurrencias de ceros.

Por ejemplo, si el string es "11000110101", entonces tu función debe retornar 1 (ya que hay 6 unos y 5 ceros):
mi intento frustrado:

```
   string = int(0) or string = int(1)
    if string.count()
    else.
```

y literalmente me quede ahi no tengo idea que mas hacer.

Comment: Primero: debes escribir una función, ¿has escrito la definición de una función?. Segundo: la función debe recibir una variable de tipo `string`. ¿Tienes ya la variable de tipo `string` que recibirá tu función?. Tercero: en tu función debes contar cuantos 1's y cuantos 0's tiene tu `string`. ¿Ya has averiguado cómo contar apariciones de caracteres en un `string`?. Último, tu función debe devolver la diferencia de restar la cantidad de 1's y la cantidad de 0's. ¿Sabes usar los operadores aritméticos en Python?. Con eso resuelves el problema. Saludos

Comment: Tu código es sintacticamente inválido y carece de lógica y sentido. Lo mínimo sería publicar algo que al menos no sea rechazado por Python.

Comment: bueno pues a todos muchas gracias, de veras que aprenderé de eso se trata y si, parte de mi frustración ha sido no entender bien ni mucho de la lógica ni mucho de la sintaxis, estoy aprendiendo de ceros a mis 37 años, no tengo nada que ver con código, y vi este porta me han ayudado mucho espero me sigan regañando que eso tambien me sirve. y lamento las incomodidades

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Te recomendaría que te pongas a ver la documentación o hacer algún tutorial para principiantes para que aprendas la sintaxis.

Volviendo al tema, solo con el método `count` de la clase `str` podes resolver el problema.

```
>>> def myfunc(s):
    return s.count("1") - s.count("0")

>>> myfunc("11000110101")
1
>>>
```

Comment: Por favor, leer [answer]. Evitemos responder preguntas tan mal formuladas. El sitio no es para hacer los deberes de los demás, el sitio es para responder dudas concretas o problemas prácticos que muestren claramente el intento de realizar el ejercicio. Saludos

Comment: bueno pues a todos muchas gracias, de veras que aprenderé de eso se trata y si, parte de mi frustración ha sido no entender bien ni mucho de la lógica ni mucho de la sintaxis, estoy aprendiendo de ceros a mis 37 años, no tengo nada que ver con código, y vi este porta me han ayudado mucho espero me sigan regañando que eso tambien me sirve. y lamento las incomodidades